# Is there an easy way to install Session messenger on Ubuntu/Whonix

Tags: scripts, session

Session messenger https://getsession.org is great, yet for some releases of Ubuntu and for Whonix in particular the installation is way too frustrating. In particular **Whonix doesn't allow installing this messenger by default due to absence of its repository in the list of approved Whonix repos**. Is there any easy way to solve the problem?

Comment: Describe the actual problem in the question, please

Comment: Hello, muru! Please inform if bold text explains the issue well enough. Thank you!

Comment: That seems to be a Whonix problem (whatever that is). What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the a kind of scripted logic that I've found best working for myself:

1.

```
   sudo curl -so /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/oxen.gpg https://deb.oxen.io/pub.gpg
```

2. Use force 'trusted' as for some versions like Whonix there is no other way to complete the installation.

   ```
   echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://deb.oxen.io $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oxen.list
   ```
3. 

```
   sudo apt update
```

4. Most of the time this goes fine and without errors for Ubuntu, still if you face any on Whonix proceed with step 5.

   ```
   sudo apt install session-desktop
   ```
5. Use this step *only* if you've faced troubles on step 4.

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   ```
6. Run `sudo apt install session-desktop`